# Getting Current Date Time for a Random Number Generator's Seed

Tags: java, time, long-integer, scalar

Preferably as a long.

All the example I can find are getting the date/time as a string and not any scalar value. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you *really* want the current time as a long, try [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()). Alternatively, you can use [`new Date().getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()).

However, using the current time as a random number generator seed is a very poor choice (at least, if you are using the random numbers for anything important, such as cryptography). You may wish to consider using a random source such as `/dev/urandom` (if available on your platform).

Comment: Note also that the standard Java random number generator, java.util.Random, by default initializes to System.currentTimeMillis(), so if that's the generator you're using, no need to do that explicitly.

Comment: Security is most definitely NOT important. It's justing ordering of some questions, which up until this point had be done by some constants. :P

Comment: Java has java.security.SecureRandom, so there is no need to use /dev/urandom directly. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: @WilliamPietri is it [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), or internals?

Answer (score 1):

System.currentTimeMillis returns a long.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

there is also System.nanoTime().

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random number you can use this code:

```
var randomnumber=new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * randomnumber) + 1); 
document.write(rand);
```